# Ctrl-U doesn't work in MacVim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (in normal mode) doesn't work in my MacVim, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> works fine. Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> does nothing, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> works as extected. Could anyone help me please?

I'm using MacVim 7.4 and OS X 10.10.3. I'm sure it was fine a month ago, but I don't remember exactly when it went wrong. It could be Yosemite that I upgraded from Marvericks like a week ago.

In more details:

- It's only the case at GUI(no problem in vim on a terminal)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in other software(such as Eclipse) are fine
- :nmap tells me there is no map for C-U or C-O(meaning default, right?)
- When I delete .vimrc, .gvimrc, and all the plugin, I still have the same problem
- When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, strangely enough it works(page-up)
- Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> navigates back in jumplist

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stupid question, Are you at the top of your document? Does macvim receive the correct keycode? What is the output of `<c-v><c-d>` in insert mode. It should output `^D`.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, the Japanese IM was hooking the key and MacVim didn't receive it. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that it's caused by the new Japanese IM which was introduced in Yosemite. The IM has a setting called "Enable Windows-like key operations" in the system preferences. I have no idea what the setting means, but disabling it solved my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What's an `IM` please?

Comment: I guess it stands for Input Method. It's like FEP(front end processor), a.k.a. IME(input method editor), in Windows.

Comment: @gpsoft thank you very much for your post, had the same problem.